# What makes a magical beast magic?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

In Harry Potter, there are many instances of fantastic beasts. What makes those beasts magic? Why is a Flesh-eating slug magic, for example, but not a Venus Flytrap?

Not a dupe of [How does a Flobberworm differ from a regular worm?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185799/how-does-a-flobberworm-differ-from-a-regular-worm) because here I'm looking for an inherent nature (such as what makes magical things magical) but there I'm searching for any physical characteristic.

Comment: Because all of the magical beasts are.......erm.....magical.

Comment: @Valorum https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185799/how-does-a-flobberworm-differ-from-a-regular-worm

Comment: *Most* of them are obvious-- creatures with magical abilities (thestrals), or whose existence normal physics can't explain (hippogriffs). But +1 for the corner cases, like your flesh-eating slug example.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet *or whose existence normal physics can't explain (hippogriffs)* - say it to a platypus and watch him cry.